# How to to avoid angular app reacting on specific URL hash change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am currently rewriting an older version of and application where HTML is mostly generated server-side in angularJS.

Only some parts of the page are not powered by AngularJS while some of client side logic is still plain JavaScript. For URL routing we use [UI-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)
One of the cases is tabs that are used across all the application. It's current implementation contains above all rewriting location hash like this: `myapp_url?foo=bar#1, myapp_url?foo=bar#2` etc. 
Note - no slash "/" in hash part.

In my case angular block is in one of the tabs is not visible by default. So when user clicks tabs on a page, URL is changed to smth like `myapp_url?foo=bar#TAB_id`, which is not understaded by UI router and it redirects the app ( not the whole page but a angular-powered block) part to a 404 state.

Angular UI router relies on Url mask like `myapp_url?foo=bar#/my_route` - with slash symbol in hash part - so that could be a trigger.
 I am asking how/where I could add this kind of check - for angular part whether to act or skip on url change?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by creating a state with empty url, which does not interfere with url hash changes by javascript outside angularJS app.

```
  $stateProvider
        .state("base.emptyState", {
          url: "",
          template: '';
        })
```